# Maven Tycho: use multiple environments (win32, linux) during test, but only build win32 artifact

Tags: maven, jenkins, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have a Maven Tycho project, where unit tests are run with tycho-surefire-plugin.

These unit tests use the SWT library, and because I want to be able to build the project locally (win32) and on the Jenkins continous integration server (linux), I specified multiple enviroments, so that the libraries were getting pulled correctly from the p2 repos:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <environments>
        <environment>
          <os>win32</os>
          <ws>win32</ws>
          <arch>x86_64</arch>
        </environment>
        <environment>
          <os>linux</os>
          <ws>gtk</ws>
          <arch>x86_64</arch>
        </environment>
      </environments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But this also makes the build produce final artifacts for both linux and win32. I will only ever run the software on windows, so I don't need the linux artifact. I just need the libraries during unit (and possibly integration) tests on the linux machine.

Is there a setting that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module that is building the products (i.e. the one with packaging type `eclipse-repository` and goals `tycho-p2-director-plugin:materialize-products` and `tycho-p2-director-plugin:archive-products`), add again a plugin entry for the `target-platform-configuration` plugin, and list the environments you want to have final artifacts for in the configuration section.

This seems to overwrite the parent settings, and only build the desired artifacts.